# Reduce the space between images and their underlying text

Tags: html, css

I have the following which shows 4 images and under each image there is a `<a>` link, as follow:-

[image]

The problem is that if the `<a>` text only spans one line, then there will be some wasted space between the images and the links as shown above (picture 1 & 4), while if the link text spans 2 lines (picture 2 & 3) then this space will be gently occupied. Can I force the space to be eliminated regardless of the link text spanning 1 or 2 lines?

here is the HTML for building a single `<div>`

```
<div style="float: left;margin-left:0px;max-width:185px">
<img style="height:90px;width:185px" src="https://******.jpg" alt="ntitle">
<span style="font-size:9px;display:inline-block;line-height:9px">
<a target="_blank" href="http://*********">*********</a>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to start using css grid

```css
    .wrap {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
        grid-template-areas: "image1 image2" "image3 image4";
        grid-gap: 0px;
    }
    img{
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    }
    .centered {
    color: orangered;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .image1{
    position: relative;
    grid-area: image1;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: black;
    }
    .image2{
    position: relative;
    grid-area: image2;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: black;
    }
    .image3{
    position: relative;
    grid-area: image3;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: black;
    }
    .image4{
    position: relative;
    grid-area: image4;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: black;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="image1">
    <div class="centered">Centered</div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oszfvKQ.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="image2">
    <div class="centered">Centered</div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/c1OFZbI.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="image3">
    <div class="centered">Centered</div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gHaJUA8.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="image4">
    <div class="centered">Centered</div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AhxnhRC.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Everything your trying to do is posible with css grid https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp
or
https://youtu.be/FEnRpy9Xfes

Comment: thanks for the reply..now i do not want to re-engineer my code,i am trying to fix the current code instead... thanks

Comment: i guess that if the issue is the length of the link, you could just short it with google https://goo.gl/ or do a html box to input the link and hide 8+ characters ?????
Its easier to just use css grid.